# final EditText input = new EditText(this); not working?

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-alertdialog

My question has more to do with alert dialogs. The "`final`" part was just an error, not the main question.

When I try to do this:

```
void btnCriarLista_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
    alert.SetMessage ("Tem a certeza que deseja limpar a sua lista?");
    alert.SetTitle ("Atenção!");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.SetNegativeButton("Não", delegate {});

    alert.SetPositiveButton ("Sim", (senderAlert, args) => {

        File.WriteAllText(filename, "");
        Finish();
    } );

    RunOnUiThread (() => {
        alert.Show();
    } );
}
```

I get an error in "input".  What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the fact that C# doesn't have keyword `final`?

Comment: so how can I do this?

Comment: remove the word "final"?

Comment: What are you expecting `final` to do?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. You are right, sorry, I got this code from other sites, and I didn't realize this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to convert example Java code over to C#. C# does not have the concept of "final" variables like Java does - just remove the `final` modifier and you should be fine:

```
EditText input = new EditText(this);
```